# Date Function in Teradata

Tags: teradata

Is there a function in Teradata, that "makes" a date by giving day, month any year as parameters?
SO if I have integer parameters p1_day, p2_month, and p3_year (which are, by the way, attributes), is there a function like

```
date_function (p1_day, p2_month, and p3_year) -> for example '2013-12-11'
```

Comment: Are you asking how to convert three integer columns (year, month, and day) into a date column using SQL **or** are you asking how to format parameters from an external application into a "date" constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TD13.10+ you can create a simple SQL UDF:

```
-- (year, month, day) to date, "invalid date" error if no valid date
REPLACE FUNCTION ymd_to_date(y INTEGER, m INTEGER, d INTEGER)
RETURNS DATE
SPECIFIC ymd_to_date
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 
   ((y - 1900) * 10000 + (m * 100) + d (DATE))
```

Dieter

Answer (score 1):

One example in teradata:

```
 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:
sel cast ('11'||'-'||'12'||'-'||'12' as date format 'dd-mm-yy');

sel cast ('11'||'-'||'12'||'-'||'12' as date format 'dd-mm-yy');

 *** Query completed. One row found. One column returned.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

(((('11'||'-')||'12')||'-')||'12')
----------------------------------
                          11-12-12
```

---

So you can simply achieve your desired result by following query:

```
sel cast (cast(p1_day as char(2))||'-'||cast(p2_month as char(2))||'-'||
cast(p3_year as char(2)) as date format 'dd-mm-yy');
```

P.S. : There doesn't seem any such built-in function in teradata.

Answer (score 0):

As far i as i know there is no predefined date function where you pass the integers and it returns the date.. however you can write you know UDF..

Comment: Another way to do is to use of the cast function
 CAST('16/06/2013' AS DATE FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYY')

Answer (score 0):

To add to Deiter's function, look at the below queries. Teradata stores dates as Integers with an offset from 1900.

```
   SELECT CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS INTEGER);

    ---- 1150818

    SELECT CURRENT_DATE;

    --- 2015-08-18

---- the format of storage is (<year> - 1900)mmdd
    SELECT (2015 -1900)*100000 + (8 * 100)+ 18;

    ------ 1150818
```

115 years from 1900, month followed by date.